# How to undo modifications made to Graphics?

Tags: graphics, undo

If one selects and drags any line inside a plot, it becomes impossible to undo this modification using `ctrl-z`.

Example:

- Create a plot: `Plot[{x^2, Sin[x]}, {x, -1, 1}]`
- Select one of the curves and move it aside.
- Try to undo this movement using `ctrl-z`.

After first `ctrl-z` nothing happens. After second the plot disappears.

How can one undo modification of graphics?

Comment: Things like this may not even be generally possible. The front end only even got multiple undo in version 10. Given the complexities of the box language and tracking these modifications I would not be surprised if it's just not implemented.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that not yet been implemented in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you asking for is currently not possible. When you edit a the output of `Plot` in the manner you describe, you make the plot graphic independent, i.e., no longer related to the `Plot` expression (note the cell is no longer grouped with the code). Such an independent graphic is like one created with the drawing tools palette. Some operations with these tools can be undone, others not. To see if the last operation you performed can be undone, check whether or not Edit > Undo is enabled (black rather than grayed out). In the case of moving a curve from a plot graphic, Undo will be grayed out.

Comment: Thank you. I will send a feature request to WR.